# Normal Spaces properties

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading about normal spaces, the next proposition is used to prove another fact, but I'm stucked in the proof of this one:

If $(X,\tau)$ is a normal topological space <=> For every closed subset $F$ of $X$ and every open subset $U$ of  $X$ such that $F \subseteq U$, exists an open subset $V$ of $X$ such that $F \subseteq V \subseteq cl_X(V) \subseteq U$

I've already proved that Normality implies the other condition, but I'm not sure how to proceed with sufficiency.

Any help is welcome, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question in such a way that it becomes more clear what are the statements involved in the theorem and how they are logically related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ and $G$ are closed and disjoint, then $F \subseteq U=X\setminus G$ which is open. The condition gives an open $V$, and then observe that $V$ and $X\setminus \textrm{cl}(V)$ are disjoint open neighbourhoods of $F$ and $G$ resp.

Comment: Thank you very much !